# What's the derivative of the wave function of hydrogen atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction

I'm trying to solve a quantum mechanics exercise.

I've got the wave function:

$$\psi(\vec{r})=\phi_{n,l,m}\left(\vec{r}\right)e^{\frac{iqx}{\hbar}}$$

where $\phi_{n,l,m}\left(\vec{r}\right)$ is the wave function of hydrogen atom with quantum numbers $n,l,m$. I need to calculate the expectation value $\langle\hat{p}_x\rangle$ for the wave function $\psi\left(\vec{r}\right)$.

That's what I tried to do:

$$\langle\hat{p}_x\rangle=\int d^3\vec{r}\langle\psi\vert\vec{r}\rangle\langle\vec{r}\vert\ \hat{p}_x\vert\psi\rangle=\int d^3\vec{r}\phi_{n,l,m}^*\left(\vec{r}\right)e^{-\frac{iqx}{\hbar}}\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\phi_{n,l,m}\left(\vec{r}\right)e^{\frac{iqx}{\hbar}}\right)$$

The derivative should result:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\phi_{n,l,m}\left(\vec{r}\right)e^{\frac{iqx}{\hbar}}\right)=\frac{\partial\phi_{n,l,m}}{\partial x}e^{\frac{iqx}{\hbar}}+\frac{iq}{\hbar}\phi_{n,l,m}\left(\vec{r}\right)e^{\frac{iqx}{\hbar}}$$

So I get:

$$\langle\hat{p}_x\rangle=\frac{\hbar}{i}\left[\int d^3\vec{r}\phi_{n,l,m}^*\left(\vec{r}\right)\frac{\partial\phi_{n,l,m}}{\partial x}+\frac{iq}{\hbar}\underbrace{\int d^3\vec{r}\left|\phi_{n,l,m}\right|^2}_{=1}\right]=q+\frac{\hbar}{i}\int d^3\vec{r}\phi_{n,l,m}^*\left(\vec{r}\right)\frac{\partial\phi_{n,l,m}}{\partial x}$$

I suspect the integral $\int d^3\vec{r}\phi_{n,l,m}^*\left(\vec{r}\right)\frac{\partial\phi_{n,l,m}}{\partial x}$ should be zero but I don't know how to calculate it because $\phi_{n,l,m}\left(\vec{r}\right)$ is expressed in spherical coordinates so I should transform $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ knowing that $x=r\sin\theta\cos\phi$ but I've never done that and I don't think that's the way to solve it. Is it possible that I've done something wrong?

Comment: the wavefunction has the wrong form: there is no $e^{iqx/\hbar}$ in any hydrogen wavefunction.  Why do you need such a factor?  Moreover, why restricted to $x$ whereas the rest of the function is a function of $\vec r$?

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates).

Comment: @ZeroTheHero $\psi$ is the wave function given me by the exercise, it says that "an electron is in the state described by the wave function $\psi$". The expected value of $\hat{p}_x$ is also explicitly requested by the text.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero The meaning is probably that the atom is boosted in $x$-direction having momentum $q$.

Comment: @Hyperon but then, if you are separating the center-of-mass from the relative motion, the $x$ of the CoM is not the $x$ of the relative motion so $\partial_x$ for the CoM momentum commutes with the relative variables $\vec r$.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I know, that's why I said "the meaning is probably".

Comment: Looks like zero indeed; why do you suspect that? You *do* know, given the WP link, that $\partial_x= \sin\theta ~ \cos\phi~\partial_r + \cos\theta \cos\phi \frac{1}{r} \partial_\theta -\frac{\sin\phi}{r\sin\theta }\partial_\phi$, so all three terms integrate to 0 in $\phi$.

Comment: @Hyperon if you are right the question is really unclear…

Comment: If you are averse to computing, consider $x\mapsto -x$...

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thank you very much